# Request URI in HTTPS in Google API in reverse proxy server with kestrel

Tags: apache, api, reverse-proxy, kestrel-http-server

Background:
Using Kestrel with ASP.NET Core behind Apache as the reverse proxy. Use https protocol for all traffic in this website.

My question is, how can i force to respond with https instead of http in callback uri using Google API?

I got an error message after I called the Google API. The error message is "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch". I have already set the callback correctly at the Google API console with https as the protocol.

The request details is as follows:

```
> response_type=code
client_id=myclientidnum.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=http://mysub.domain.com/signin-google
scope=openid profile email
state=long_long_code
```

Please drop me a line if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also received the redirect_uri_mismatch error when I tried to configure Google authentication for my ASP.NET Core web application running on Apache via reverse proxy with Kestrel.

The error was due to setting the Authorized redirect URI to `https`. Once I changed it to `http`, Google authentication worked.

So assuming your domain is `example.com`, change your Authorized redirect URI from

```
https://example.com/signin-google
```

to

```
http://example.com/signin-google
```

Comment: Thanks, kimbaudi. But how do you cope with other web api call which requires https callback? e.g. Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't allow http so I just entered `https://example.com/signin-microsoft` and got authentication to work. For Twitter, I entered `https://example.com/signin-twitter` as well. For Facebook, I entered `http://example.com/signin-facebook` and it worked. So far, I've successfully enabled authentication with Facebook, Google, Twitter, and Microsoft. My approach was to first try `https` and if that doesn't work, try `http`. So far, so good.

Comment: kimbaudi, I did it for the Microsoft with https callback setting in the Microsoft API console. However, the call of the callback is still without encryption.

Comment: @userIndulgeInDChord - when you say "the call of the callback is still without encryption" for Microsoft, does that mean Microsoft authentication is not working for you? Or that it's working, but without encryption (or something else)? I was having problems enabling 3rd party authentication with Microsoft, but I got it to work via reverse proxy with Kestrel. Maybe I can help you get it working, but without encryption. Can you elaborate?

Comment: No worries. I made a mistake on configuring the startup.cs regarding the Microsoft web api settings. It's running perfectly fine now.

Comment: This is not a solution since facebook, in e.g., doesn't allow http.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the server is not using the headers forwarded by the reverse proxy so it is requesting the incorrect protocol. You need to:

1. Ensure your reverse proxy is setting X-Forward headers
2. Enable the UseForwardedHeaders middleware *before* authentication

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = 
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseAuthentication();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved this by below code.

```
           app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
                await next();
            });

            ForwardedHeadersOptions forwardOptions = new 
             ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
                RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
            };

            forwardOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            forwardOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardOptions);
```

Now that google and facebook doesnot support http redirects in production apps and kestrel behind reverse proxy is running on http had faced same issue. I forced the schema on all the requests to https (this is safe bet i had behind a https reverse proxy) using above code and everything worked fine